# WScript.Shell not working in FireFox

Tags: javascript

I have following javascript code. (Actually I have to launch an exe on client side)

```
function executeCommands()
{  
      var commandtoRun ="C:\\WINDOWS\\notepad.exe";   
      var oShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
      oShell.run(commandtoRun);                                               
}
```

This code can launch notepad in the Internet Explorer when I made Security option to "Low" but this code can't launch Notepad in FireFox.

Any suggestion will be appreciated..

Answer (score 1):

Firefox doesn't support `ActiveXObject()`, it's a proprietary feature of JScript (Microsoft's version of JavaScript).

Read more information [here](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/ActiveX).

Comment: So is there any other way to launch an exe using javascript? I already used Shell.Application but it doesn't work...

Comment: @jitendra, you'd have to write your own extension for Firefox.  It's simply not possible due to security restrictions.  *Shell.Application* is also an ActiveX control.  Please read the link I added to my answer.

Comment: You woldn't want websites to remotely launch exe files. Thats what the Firefox team thought and thats what Microsoft thought but they didn't care.