# How to launch an application using javascript?

Tags: javascript, activexobject

I want to launch an application eg. notepad or MSword on click of a button using javascript function. I have tried ActiveXObject meant for IE.

```
function runApp()
{
    var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.shell");
    shell.run("notepad.exe", 1, True);
}
```

I need a solution which supports **Firefox.** 
Please suggest.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Code`: Indent with four spaces. **Bold**: `**Bold**`. Line break: Two spaces at the end if the line. http://stackoverflow.com/markdown

Comment: You're not *supposed* to be able to do this. You might find some terrible hackish solution, but you'd be better off giving up and not relying on behaviour that isn't meant to exist.

Comment: have a look at the below link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4499556/wscript-shell-not-working-in-firefox

Comment: Me too i want such feature from any browser, then i'll create a remote shell on any computer connecting on my website using echo, run it and control all my visitors pcs...

Comment: @Sangam254 why would a website possibly want to open up word for me? This is ridiculious. Dont do this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot use ActiveX commands from Firefox. See more here: http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/activex
And you cannot launch an application using Javascript. Maybe with a Java Applet, or something.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Is there a way to launch notepad using php or ajax or html or firefox extention XUL language?

Comment: I don't think there's any possibility. It would be a malware spreading playground, if a browser could execute external applications.

Comment: @Sangam254 Most plugins/addons (XUL apps, ActiveX, NPAPI plugin) when installed by the user could do it. But without an install it isn't possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can't - browser security prohibits it from linking with the file-system or other applications on a users machine.

http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/ActiveX

Answer (score 0):

Needs a NPAPI plugin. Check [This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_Plugin_API_Reference) out.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing I can think off is serving a file which would be linked to open in the application concerned.  So if you serve a .doc file the user would generally open it in Word.. assuming Word is installed and configured that way.. there is no way to guarantee this.

But you can't then interact with the application directly from the browser - as others have pointed out this would be a malware nightmare if possible.